# C# Asp.net core Dependency injection using RestSharp

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am currently using RestClient to fetch data from a website.
I would like to be able to use dependency injection in the controller class in my asp.net core project that uses the Client class.
When I try to use the dependency injection when I make the call to the controller and put a breakpoint into the controller it does not get hit. This is because I have not setup the Client dependency injection correctly.

Below is my Client class that implementents the IClient interface.

```
public class Client: IClient
{
    public RestClient RestClient { get; set; }
    public Client()
    {
        RestClient = new RestClient("https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/");
    }

    public async Task<List<EventDTO>> GetAll()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("events", Method.GET);
        var content = await RestClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(request);
        return Event;
    }

    public async Task<RootObject> Get(string id)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("events?source=" + "InciWeb", Method.GET);
        RootObject content = null;
        content = await RestClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(request);
        return content;
    }
}
```

In the startup ConfigureServices method.

```
  services.AddTransient<IClient, Client>();
```

in my controller i have do the following:

```
private readonly IClient _client;

public EventsController(IClient client)
{
    _client = client;
}
```

I not sure if i could creating any instance of the client in the constructor.
Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Could you rephrase your question/problem? It doesn't seem very clear

Comment: If you are asking whether you can inject your dependencies through constructor, the answer is a definite yes.  Constructor injection is almost always preferable over property injection which is not deterministic with some of the IoC containers. So your code above should work as far the dependency injection goes.  However, there are some design issues with your code.  If this is a production code, I would recommend you refactor.

Comment: The constructor injection is not working for me and I do not understand why.

Comment: @GreatKhan2016 Can you elaborate on what's not working?  Is the `_client` field in the controller `null` at runtime?  There are some design issues with the code like hard coded url instead of the client providing it, not using .ConfigureAwait(false) for the awaitables, etc.

Comment: Actually it is working now. I understand that hard coded urls is bad, but why would i need to use configureAwait false and what else is wrong :( ?

Comment: Glad it is working.  You will have to read up on the asynchronous programming in C# (asyn/await) for the ConfigureAwait().  You probably don't need it in your example above but in a production environment, you will want the client in a library with the configureawait set to false for performance reason.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach would be you injecting IRestClient into your client.
Then create your RestRequest and execute with the injectable IRestClient

Please the example below

```
     public class Client : IClient
    {
        private readonly IRestClient _restClient;
        public Client(IRestClient restClient)
        {
            _restClient = restClient;
            _restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/");
        }

        public async Task<List<EventDTO>> GetAll()
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("events", Method.GET);
            var content = await _restClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(request);
            return content.Event;
        }

        public async Task<RootObject> Get(string id)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("events?source=" + "InciWeb", Method.GET);
            RootObject content = null;
            content = await _restClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(request);
            return content;
        }
    }
```

Register IRestClient as Transient and your Client as Singleton into IServiceCollection
Please check the example ConfigureServices

```
  services.AddTransient<IRestClient, RestClient>();
  services.AddSingleton<IClient, Client>();
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: I've got to go read the RestSharp docs because I really hate the idea that I'm supposed to "new up" a `RestRequest` in my code since that seems to make unit testing either impossible, or REALLY tricky.

Comment: This answer needs an upgrade since v107 deprecates IRestClient

Comment: RestSharp removed `IRestClient` only not the `RestClient` class.
Now you can just inject `RestClient` class. 
Do not instantiate RestClient for each HTTP call. RestSharp creates a new instance of HttpClient internally, and you will get lots of hanging connections, and eventually exhaust the connection pool. In your DI, you must register your API client as a singleton.

Comment: Would you have an implementation example with the new version (v107)?

Comment: `services.AddSingleton< RestClient >(new RestClient (new RestClientOptions()));` @Carlos

Comment: "I apologize for my delayed response. I was occupied with a new job. However, I will try to be more active on StackOverflow from now on. By the way, if you are using .NET 5 or later versions, you can explore the built-in HTTP client provided by `dotnet`. They have made a few changes, and I am yet to assess if `restsharp` would be beneficial over HTTPClient from `.net`."